# SSIS Export to Excel from sql in specific cells on left side even though data exists on right side

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm trying to send the data into Excel from SQL using SSIS in specific cells. Currently using Excel template that has data in right side columns.

Example: Need to send data to A1, A2 in excel and B1,B2 has the data that already exists. When I preview the data in excel in ssis it is showing Null in A1 and A2 and it starts inserting from A3. Need to insert data from A1. Any thoughts on this?

Currently It is showing up like this in excel preview in ssis:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:B2]
```

Data

```
A     |  B
---------
Null  |   1
Null  |   2
```

Need to populate data beside 1. It is starting to insert from line 3

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirements but if it's anything other than dumping tabular dat into Excel, you need to use a scripting language to do it. This could be a .Net script inside SSIS or it coud be some kind of standalone script

Comment: So you need to insert excel data into A regardless of what's in B already? Or is the data in B somehow related to what's in Excel?

Comment: Need to insert excel data into A regardless of what's in B already